# Charts don't fit into <div> (highcharts, MVC) Bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

my page is going to be divided into four equal parts and each part should contain a graph. I'd like graphs to be scaled according to size of the parent `<div>` + padding.
For creating graphs I use dotnet highcharts library but I don't know how to fit charts into the `<div>`. Here is my code so far:

cshtml divided into four rectangles:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@model ChartsModel

<div id="main">
    <div id="nw" class="rectangles">
        @Model.Charts[0]
    </div>
    <div id="ne" class="rectangles">
        @Model.Charts[1]
    </div>
    <div id="sw" class="rectangles">
        @Model.Charts[2]
    </div>
    <div id="se" class="rectangles">
        @Model.Charts[3]
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body { height: 100vh; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #DDD;}
.rectangles { width: 50%; height: 40vh; float: left; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px;}
#nw { background: #DDD; border: 1px solid red; }
#ne { background: #DDD; border: 1px solid red; }
#sw { background: #DDD; border: 1px solid red; }
#se { background: #DDD; border: 1px solid red; }
#main { margin: 0 10vh 10%; }
#line { height: 40px ; background: red; }
```

My model:

```
public class ChartsModel
{
    public List<Highcharts> Charts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I get when I insert four random charts from highcharts examples. Width is correct, but height of charts is not:
[Wrong_height_charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF9YV.png)

In above examples, if I try to switch `vh` for `%` in `height` css settings, then height of graphs is correct, but width gets wrong and I loose margin at the bottom of the page: [Wrong_width_and_margin_charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYhrQ.png)

Do you know any solution so that charts fit my `<div>` and margins/paddings are correct as they should? Or should I use different library then highchart?
Thank you for help.

EDIT:
OK, I don't know if it some bug of dotnet highcharts, but height sizing does not work even with one graph, [image: see here]

All I am using is this:

```
<div style="height:300px; width:500px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="height: 100%; width:100%;">@Model</div>
</div>
```

According to this fiddle it should work http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/446/ (if you remove OFF from container). I think I will have to use different approach or library.

Comment: due to padding:10px, charts moved down in case of height in vh

Comment: trying removing that paading -top , by giving padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px

Comment: Hi, this did not help. I edited my question, in my opinion this library is bugged or something.

Comment: Can try reducing height to 30vh?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/wkkAd/492/

Comment: you were using wrong id(#OFF-container) in CSS, i t should be #container, after fixing it is showing correcting...check this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/wkkAd/492/

Answer (score 0):

you were using wrong id(#OFF-container) in CSS, and it should be #container.

After updating the id to #container in CSS ,chart is getting displayed correctly, check this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/wkkAd/492/

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I know it works, that's why I write "According to this fiddle it should work" :) . But with dotnet highcharts it doesn't work If I create basically the same in MVC...

Comment: @xYann00 reducing height to 30vh might help to fit that chart properly